# How to use Jax vmap over zipped arguments?

Tags: python, jax

I have the following example code that works with a regular `map`

```py
def f(x_y):
    x, y = x_y
    return x.sum() + y.sum()

xs = [jnp.zeros(3) for i in range(4)]
ys = [jnp.zeros(2) for i in range(4)]

list(map(f, zip(xs, ys)))

# returns:
[DeviceArray(0., dtype=float32),
 DeviceArray(0., dtype=float32),
 DeviceArray(0., dtype=float32),
 DeviceArray(0., dtype=float32)]
```

How can I use `jax.vmap` instead? The naive thing is:

```py
jax.vmap(f)(zip(xs, ys))
```

but this gives:

```
ValueError: vmap was requested to map its argument along axis 0, which implies that its rank should be at least 1, but is only 0 (its shape is ())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using [`jax.vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.vmap.html#jax-vmap), you do not need to zip your variables. You can write what you want like below:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import vmap

def f(x_y):
    x, y = x_y
    return x.sum() + y.sum()

xs = jnp.zeros((4,3))
ys = jnp.zeros((4,2))
vmap(f)((xs, ys))
```

Output:

```
DeviceArray([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this basically solves it for me. Looks like the key thing is making xs/ys 2D arrays rather than lists of arrays. But I'm still curious if there's an `in_axes` choice (or something else) that would make it work with lists of arrays?

Comment: `vmap` can only map over array axes. The only way to make it map over elements of a list is to first use `jnp.array()` to convert the list to an array.

Answer (score 3):

`vmap` is designed to map over multiple variables by default, so no `zip` is needed. Furthermore, it can only map over array axes, not over elements of lists or tuples. So a more canonical way to to write your example would be to convert your lists to arrays and do something like this:

```py
def g(x, y):
  return x.sum() + y.sum()

xs_arr = jnp.asarray(xs)
ys_arr = jnp.asarray(ys)

jax.vmap(g)(xs_arr, ys_arr)
# DeviceArray([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```